# Performance benefits to using Native modules for HTTP calls over JS?

Tags: react-native

For my react native application I have a node project which represents the SDK for my API. The SDK encapsulates the REST API calls and session management within native code for each platform. Currently the native API calls are asynchronous and make use of Promises via the react native bridge for communication back to JS.

There are a couple of new requirements which would involve converting the SDK to a JS based implementation and make use `fetch` for the API calls. My concern is what (if any) performance degradations this will have compared to the current native implementation?

Would there be any advantages in terms of performance in keeping the API calls in the native layer? Or is the fetch implementation doing the same thing anyway?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There's plenty of things that are faster in native than JS (I'd really avoid JS for anything computationally expensive... actually I'd try to avoid JS for anything).  But http calls are one area I wouldn't worry about.  The amount of time spent sending the request to the network and waiting for the response will dwarf the amount of time spent in handling it on the client in either language.